# How to change document by terms dataframe into a dataframe which records the documents where a word appears

Tags: python, pandas

I have a
[image: documents by terms dataframe]
I want to change the dataframe into the format like
[image: this]
Could you tell me how to code with pandas, is there any built-in function in pandas which can be used to do it.

```
doc_term_frame=pd.DataFrame(data={'doc_id':[1,2,3,4],'words':[['w1','w2'],['w2','w3'],['w4','w5'],['w4','w6']]}).set_index('doc_id')
desired_frame=pd.DataFrame(data={'word':['w1','w2','w3','w4','w5','w6'],'doc_ids':[[1],[1,2],[2],[3,4],[3],[4]]}).set_index('word')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pd.concat`

```
w = pd.concat({k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in df.words.iteritems()})
pd.Series(
    w.index.get_level_values(0)
).groupby(w.values).apply(list).to_frame(name='doc_ids')

   doc_ids
w1     [1]
w2  [1, 2]
w3     [2]
w4  [3, 4]
w5     [3]
w6     [4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DataFrame` constructor for creating convert `lists` to rows, then reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), create columns from index by reseting index, `groupby` and create list. Last convert `Series` to `DataFrame` by [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(doc_term_frame['words'].values.tolist(), index=doc_term_frame.index)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name='word')
        .groupby('word')['doc_id']
        .apply(list)
        .to_frame(name='doc_ids')
print (df1)

     doc_ids
word        
w1       [1]
w2    [1, 2]
w3       [2]
w4    [3, 4]
w5       [3]
w6       [4]
```

Comment: Thank you, your posts is what I am looking for, I am not familiar with stack/unstack function, I think I need more practices with python.